# Compose a link based in select's option value

Tags: javascript, html, forms, html-select

I have 2 dropdown menus, and I need to compose a link with it's values.

Here is the code:

```
<form id="dropdown1">
    <select id="linha">
        <option value="G12">Option 1</option>
        <option value="G11">Option 2</option>
        <option value="H89">Option 3</option>
    </select>
    <select id="dia">
        <option value="all">Every day</option>
        <option value="work">working days</option>
        <option value="sat">saturday</option>
        <option value="sun">sunday</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

I need something in JavaScript to "compose" a link with `http://somewebsite.com/*selected_linha_value*/*selected_dia_value*`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at: http://jsfiddle.net/ERHhA/

You can use [jQuery val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to get the value of the select boxes. Then just append these values to the base url.

`var url = "http://somewebsite.com/" + $('#linha').val() + "/" + $('#dia').val();`

Comment: Awesome! What if i want a button to open the composed link instead of a alert?

Comment: instead of alert(url); i can use open(url); Thanks!!

Comment: Or, `window.location = url;`.

Comment: Not exactly, correctly it is: `document.location.href = url;`

Answer (score 4):

```
    <select name="dia" id="dia">
      <option value="all">Every day</option>
      <option value="http://stackoverflow.com">working days</option>
      <option value="http://anotherSite.com">saturday</option>
      <option value="http://anotherSite2.com">sunday</option>
    </select>
    <script>
    $("#dia").change(function () {
              var selctedValue = "";
              $("select option:selected").each(function () {
                    selctedValue += $(this).val();
window.location.href = selctedValue;

    });
    });
```

Comment: The code would be HUGE if i had to do for each option i had. 551 options in the first select

Answer (score 3):

i think u need something like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
params = getParams();
var name1 = unescape(params["linha"]);
switch(name1)
{
case "g12":
window.location = "http://www.google.com"
}

function getParams(){
var idx = document.URL.indexOf('?');

var params = new Array();
if (idx != -1) {
var pairs = document.URL.substring(idx+1, document.URL.length).split('&');
for (var i=0; i<pairs.length; i++){
nameVal = pairs[i].split('=');
params[nameVal[0]] = nameVal[1];
}
}
return params;
}
```

Its not the full code. It will give you some idea. If you have any doubt just comment

Comment: It's good, but smiledge's answer was perfect to me, as i have 551 options in the first select... Thank you

Comment: Sorry dude. I saw the link option u provided below the code late only. anyway u got ur answer. dats all

Answer (score 2):

What about this one?

```js
function make_url(){
    var linha = document.getElementById('linha').value;
    var dia = document.getElementById('dia').value;
    var url=window.location.href;
    var pos=url.indexOf('?');
    if (pos>-1){
        url = url.substr(0,pos);
    }
    //alert(url + '?linha='+linha+'&dia='+dia); return;
    document.location.href = url + '?linha='+linha+'&dia='+dia;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JbcUF/)

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <select class="small-nav">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Go To</option> 
    <option value="http://whiterabbitexpress.com">Services</option>
    <option value="http://shop.whiterabbitjapan.com">Shop</option>
</div><!-- container -->
```

JScript:

```
$(".small-nav").change(function() {
        window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
    });
```